# Absolute positioning not relative to the correct element

Tags: html, position, absolute

The div with style contentdetailleft is absolute and so will be positioned to the div with the style container (since container is absolute). You can see that I have set left to 0px and top to 0px just to illustrate this. If you run it you will see the div with contentdetailleft overlap the div with style contentTop as you would expect. This is the HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Charts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding:0;
 background-color: blue;
}

h3 {
 margin: .5em;
 color: black;
}

.container { 
 width:98%;margin:1%;height:96%;overflow:auto;position:absolute;
}

.containerTop { 
 width:100%;height:auto;
}

.containerBottom { 
 width:100%;margin-top:40px;height:auto;
}

.contentheaderleft { 
 width:20%;float:left;height:40px;left:0px;top:0px;position:absolute;border:1px solid #ddd;color:#666;background-color:yellow; 
}

.contentheaderright {
 width:77%;float:left;overflow:auto;overflow:hidden;margin-left:1%;position:absolute;left:21%;height:40px;border:1px solid #ddd;color:#666; background-color: red;
}

.contentdetailleft { 
 width:20%;height:89%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;border: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #fbf9ee; 
}

.contentdetailright { 
 width:77%;float:left;overflow:auto;overflow:hidden;margin-left:1%;position: absolute;left:21%;height: 89%;border: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #fbf9ee; 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <label id="spn" style="display:none"></label>
 <label id="spnstring" style="display:none"></label>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="containerTop">
   <div class="contentheaderleft">
     <h3 align="center">Widget</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="contentheaderright">
    <h3 align="center">Drop Your Widget Here</h3>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="containerBottom">
   <div id="leftdiv" class="contentdetailleft">
   </div>
   <div class="contentdetailright" id="rightsec">
   </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now remove the left:0px and top:0px on the contentdetailleft style (see the HTML below). Now the div with style contentdetailleft is within the div with style contentBottom. How can this be?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Charts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding:0;
 background-color: blue;
}

h3 {
 margin: .5em;
 color: black;
}

.container { 
 width:98%;margin:1%;height:96%;overflow:auto;position:absolute;
}

.containerTop { 
 width:100%;height:auto;
}

.containerBottom { 
 width:100%;margin-top:40px;height:auto;
}

.contentheaderleft { 
 width:20%;float:left;height:40px;left:0px;top:0px;position:absolute;border:1px solid #ddd;color:#666;background-color:yellow; 
}

.contentheaderright {
 width:77%;float:left;overflow:auto;overflow:hidden;margin-left:1%;position:absolute;left:21%;height:40px;border:1px solid #ddd;color:#666; background-color: red;
}

.contentdetailleft { 
 width:20%;height:89%;position:absolute;border: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #fbf9ee; 
}

.contentdetailright { 
 width:77%;float:left;overflow:auto;overflow:hidden;margin-left:1%;position: absolute;left:21%;height: 89%;border: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #fbf9ee; 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <label id="spn" style="display:none"></label>
 <label id="spnstring" style="display:none"></label>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="containerTop">
   <div class="contentheaderleft">
     <h3 align="center">Widget</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="contentheaderright">
    <h3 align="center">Drop Your Widget Here</h3>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="containerBottom">
   <div id="leftdiv" class="contentdetailleft">
   </div>
   <div class="contentdetailright" id="rightsec">
   </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks
Ian

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean... 'How can this be?' The left div is on top of the header; you've given them the same position so what was the expected outcome?

Comment: Hi. I am saying that if I add left=0px and top0px to the left div then it is placed below the header. If I do not add these then it is placed over the header. The left div should be positioned according to the container so how does adding left=0px and top=0px work? Basically in the second example why is the left div not over the header since its parent absolute positioned item is the container?

Comment: If you modify the HTML as follows:

a) Add two new styles

.contentdetailleft1 { 
 width:20%;height:50px;position:absolute;top:auto;border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.contentdetailleft2 { 
 width:20%;height:50px;position:absolute;top:auto;border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

and change the containerBottom to this:

  <div class="containerBottom">
   <div id="leftdiv1" class="contentdetailleft1" style="background-color:green;">
   </div>
   <div id="leftdiv2" class="contentdetailleft2" style="background-color:orange;">
   </div>
   <div class="contentdetailright" id="rightsec">
   </div>
          </div>

Comment: Following on from the previous comment ... Why do I not see the green and orange div? Both styles are auto and they should follow each other shouldn't they? None of this makes sense to me!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing this change in behavior is because the default positioning that occurs when you use "position: absolute;" is "left: 0;". However, "top: 0;" is not default behavior, so when you add that (as you correctly said), ".contentdetailleft" is positioned to the ".container" element.

Because ".contentdetailleft" comes after ".contentheaderleft" in the DOM (*and more importantly, because ".containerBottom" and ".containerTop" are still default position - static), once ".containerdetailleft" becomes positioned absolutely it is pulled out of the normal flow of the DOM and positioned based on it's relative/absolute parent (".container"). At this point it is sitting at the top-left corner of container, on top of ".containerTop", and thus on top of ".contentheaderleft".

You don't need the style "left: 0;" on ".contentdetailleft" once it has been positioned absolutely. If you would like to keep it absolute and have the "top" styling, but not have it overlap/cover ".contentheaderleft", simply position it from the top at the exact height of ."contentheaderleft" (42px), i.e. "top: 42px;".

*see below, all I updated was the top position of ".contentdetailleft"

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Charts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding:0;
 background-color: blue;
}

h3 {
 margin: .5em;
 color: black;
}

.container { 
 width:98%;margin:1%;height:96%;overflow:auto;position:absolute;
}

.containerTop { 
 width:100%;height:auto;
}

.containerBottom { 
 width:100%;margin-top:40px;height:auto;
}

.contentheaderleft { 
 width:20%;float:left;height:40px;left:0px;top:0px;position:absolute;border:1px solid #ddd;color:#666;background-color:yellow; 
}

.contentheaderright {
 width:77%;float:left;overflow:auto;overflow:hidden;margin-left:1%;position:absolute;left:21%;height:40px;border:1px solid #ddd;color:#666; background-color: red;
}

.contentdetailleft { 
 width:20%;height:89%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:42px;border: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #fbf9ee; 
}

.contentdetailright { 
 width:77%;float:left;overflow:auto;overflow:hidden;margin-left:1%;position: absolute;left:21%;height: 89%;border: 1px solid #ddd; background-color: #fbf9ee; 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <label id="spn" style="display:none"></label>
 <label id="spnstring" style="display:none"></label>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="containerTop">
   <div class="contentheaderleft">
     <h3 align="center">Widget</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="contentheaderright">
    <h3 align="center">Drop Your Widget Here</h3>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="containerBottom">
   <div id="leftdiv" class="contentdetailleft">
   </div>
   <div class="contentdetailright" id="rightsec">
   </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So just to confirm my understanding if I take out top:42px and left:0px from contentdetailleft it still works. This means that be default it is positioned below the header without setting left or top. How does this work?

Comment: the reason it also works if you take out both is because when you position an element as 'absolute', this carries with it the default styling of 'top: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: 0;

That is why you can remove 'left: 0;' without any change - because it's already the default. And when you take away 'top: 42px;', '.contentdetailleft' goes back to the default absolute behavior of 'top: auto;', and therefore "knows" that '.contentheaderleft' is above and positions itself

End result will be exactly the same if you keep or remove 'left:0px' and add 'top:auto;' instead of 'top:42px;'

Comment: OK. So with the default behaviour of top:auto, contentdetailleft positions itself below contentheaderleft even though contentheaderleft is static and even though the parent of .contentdetailleft is the .container? Doesn't that go against the documentation? I always thought that absolute was always relative to the first parent that is relative or absolute?

Comment: So does auto really mean ignore what you have been told and position yourself below the previous element in the DOM?

Comment: essentially, yup haha. gotta love positioning defaults

Comment: If you modify the HTML as follows:Add two new styles .contentdetailleft1 { width:20%;height:50px;position:absolute;top:auto;border: 1px solid #ddd; } .contentdetailleft2 { width:20%;height:50px;position:absolute;top:auto;border: 1px solid #ddd; } and change the containerBottom to this: <div class="containerBottom"> <div id="leftdiv1" class="contentdetailleft1" style="background-color:green;"> </div> <div id="leftdiv2" class="contentdetailleft2" style="background-color:orange;"> </div> <div class="contentdetailright" id="rightsec"> </div> </div>

Comment: Following on from the previous comment ... Why do I not see the green and orange div? Both styles are auto and they should follow each other shouldn't they? None of this makes sense to me! – Sputnik 16 hours ago